# How to use ImageProcessor/DetectEdges in visual basic?

Tags: .net, vba, visual-studio, image-processing, imageprocessor

I trying to use ImageProcessor / DetectEdges. But I get the error in the picture. What am I doing wrong? Many thanks to the me helpers.[Error Visual Studio Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihynb.jpg)

Comment: I use wrong labels? Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not newing up an instance of the filter.

Your methods call should be

```cs
imageFactory.DetectEdges(new KayyaliEdgeFilter(), true)
```